# CentOS 7 : How can i fix this Error? (Yum : Error Nothing to do)

Tags: shell, installation, sh, centos7, yum

First, I'm so sorry to my english, not perfect.

I was faced with problem while testing a `.sh` file.

That because of error `Nothing to do.`.

That phrase is the phrase that appeared when executing `yum -y install perl-CPAN`, but before that, `yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'` **worked normally**.

And It was **successful** when I typed it directly instead of `yum -y install perl-CPAN`.

I tried solutions like below but the result was the same.

1. Edit and Install

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
# vi CentOS-Base.repo
   Enable =0 -> 1
# yum install epel-release
# ./setup.sh
```

ps : Many people have recommended this solutions.

2. Check

check already install

check the correct install repository

Thanks to read my situation, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know what `setup.sh` you are refering to is, `yum` says `Nothing to do.` if you have the package already installed. To check if you have the package installed, you can use `rpm`. If the package is not installed, it will give you:

```
# rpm -q perl-CPAN
package perl-CPAN is not installed
```

Then if you install the package, e.g. with:

```
# yum -y install perl-CPAN
[...]
Complete!
```

Then you can verify package is installed:

```
# rpm -q perl-CPAN
perl-CPAN-2.28-5.fc33.noarch
```

Note I have tested on Fedora 33, but there should not be much difference to CentOS in this regards.